# Solving $g(n)=2g(n-1)+n+2^n$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am learning how to solve recurrence relations and I have an equation  that got me to a dead end:

$$g(n)=2g(n-1)+n+2^n$$

My problem is the non-homogeneous part.

Comment: No initial condition ?

Comment: We want a particular solution. Maybe treat $g(n)=2g(n-1)+2^n$ and $g(n)=2g(n-1)+n$ separately.

Comment: no there is no initial condition, just solve the given equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brutal way is to take:
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0} g(n)\,x^n $$
and assuming $g(0)=0$,
$$ x\cdot f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1} g(n-1)\,x^{n} $$
so:
$$ f(x)-2x f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}(n+2^n) x^n = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{2x}{1-2x} $$
leads to:
$$ f(x) = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2(1-2x)}+\frac{2x}{(1-2x)^2} $$
and now we may recover the coefficients $g(n)$ from partial fraction decomposition, leading to:

> $$ g(n) = (n+2)(2^n-1).$$

---

Alternative approach, without generating functions. If we set:
$$\Delta_n = g(n+1)-2 g(n) = n+1+2^{n+1} $$
we have:
$$\Delta_n + 2 \Delta_{n-1} +\ldots + 2^k \Delta_{n-k} = g(n+1)-2^{k+1}g(n-k)$$
so:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}\Delta_{n-k}2^k = g(n+1)-2^{n+1}g(0) $$
from which:
$$ g(n+1)=2^{n+1}g(0) + \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}2^{n+1-k}\left(k+2^{k}\right) $$
or:
$$ g(n) = 2^n g(0) + 2^n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k+2^k}{2^k} = 2^n g(0) + (n+2)(2^{n}-1).$$